# How Can I Add DeviceMotion Capabilities to a Swift Playground?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, swift-playground

I am working on a Swift playground and I am trying to use this code to get the device motion.

```
@objc func update()
{
    if let deviceMotion = motionManager.deviceMotion {
        print("Device Motion Yaw: \(deviceMotion.attitude.yaw)")
    }
}
```

However, it seems that device motion does not work on a Swift playground even though it works in iOS. How would I change a playground to support device motion? I am using an iPad running iOS 12 and the latest version of Swift Playgrounds and a Mac for the code. I know that the method gets called perfectly, and the code runs perfectly when I put it as part of an iOS app on both an iPad and an iPhone. How would I modify a playground to support this, as from my understanding it does not by default?

Comment: You can't access motion in a Playground because the playground runs a simulator and the simulator doesn't support motion (except simulated shake from the menu: Hardware -> Shake).  the MacBook doesn't have gyros anyways; neither does the iMac.

Comment: @JoshHomann Thanks for your reply. I am running the playground on the iPad. And when I use the iPad, the gyroscope works perfectly in a playground. Magnetometer and accelerometer do as well. Only device motion doesn't work. Is there a way to manually change the playground to support DeviceMotion if it does not? I read somewhere that you could somehow modify the PList file in a playground but I do not know how.

Answer (score 1):

It is entirely possible. I’ve done it on several occasions. You’ll need a `CMMotionManager` class. There are many ways to do this, but I would recommend using a timer. Here is some example code, taken from [Apple’s developer documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/coremotion/getting_processed_device-motion_data) and modified to fit the question.

```
let motion = CMMotionManager()
func startDeviceMotion() {
    if motion.isDeviceMotionAvailable {
        //How often to push updates
        self.motion.deviceMotionUpdateInterval = 1.0/60.0
        self.motion.showsDeviceMovementDisplay = true
        self.motion.startDeviceMotionUpdates(using: .xMagneticNorthZVertical)

        // Configure a timer to fetch the motion data.
        self.timer = Timer(fire: Date(), interval: (1.0 / 60.0), repeats: true,
                           block: { (timer) in
                            if let data = self.motion.deviceMotion {      
let x = data.attitude.pitch
let y = data.attitude.roll
let z = data.attitude.yaw
//Use the data                                
                            }
        })
        RunLoop.current.add(self.timer!, forMode: RunLoop.Mode.default)
    }
}
startDeviceMotionUpdates()
```

Either do that or try something like this, also from the documentation

```
func startQueuedUpdates() {
   if motion.isDeviceMotionAvailable {       self.motion.deviceMotionUpdateInterval = 1.0 / 60.0
      self.motion.showsDeviceMovementDisplay = true
      self.motion.startDeviceMotionUpdates(using: .xMagneticNorthZVertical, 
               to: self.queue, withHandler: { (data, error) in
         // Make sure the data is valid before accessing it.
         if let validData = data {
            // Get the attitude relative to the magnetic north reference frame. 
            let roll = validData.attitude.roll
            let pitch = validData.attitude.pitch
            let yaw = validData.attitude.yaw

            // Use the motion data in your app.
         }
      })
   }
}
```

Comment: Hi @Rohith Vishwajith if this or any answer has solved your question please consider [accepting it](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/5234/179419) by clicking the check-mark. This indicates to the wider community that you've found a solution and gives some reputation to both the answerer and yourself. There is no obligation to do this.