# How Can I Configure A Swift Playground File With a PList?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, swift-playground

Although Swift playgrounds seems to have support for CoreMotion (gyrometer, accelerometer, and magnetometer alll work), deviceMotion from CoreMotion doesn't seem to be built in. I have run the code as an app and it works perfectly, so I know the device I am using (2018 Wi-Fi Only iPad) has the necessary hardware. From my understanding this can be enabled with a PList in Swift playgrounds. What I want to do is add deviceMotion to a PList file (I copied and pasted a Manifest.plist file from a playground book into the playground package), and have the PList file used so that deviceMotion can work on an iPad.

I have already looked at this question:
[Read plist in swift 3 playground](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41074149/read-plist-in-swift-3-playground)
, as well as a few others, but they don't really seem to answer what I specifically want to do.

```
@objc func update()
{
    if let deviceMotion = motionManager.deviceMotion {
        print("Device Motion Yaw: \(deviceMotion.attitude.yaw)")
    }
}
```

As I stated before, I ran the same code in an app and it works perfectly, but when I run it in a playground nothing happens.

Comment: Just to clarify - are you running the playground on a Mac or are you talking about the iPad app `Swift playgrounds`?

Comment: @Losiowaty Thanks for your reply. I am talking about the iPad app Swift Playgrounds, however I can edit the same code that is run on the iPad on a Mac because it is saved and synced via iCloud Drive.

Comment: How do you know that just adding a .plist will enable CoreMotion support? I have never seen that documented somewhere.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How Can I Add DeviceMotion Capabilities to a Swift Playground?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55294421/how-can-i-add-devicemotion-capabilities-to-a-swift-playground)

Comment: @JoRa I had seen on another post that since playground runs a simulator it is not built in by default and needs to be added by a PList. I would gladly use another method as well if you knew of any, but this is what I had read so as far as I am aware this will work.